# Scope issue with titanium

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, titanium

I'm having scope issues with the tfield[] array created below. I'm creating ten rows with six cells. Each cell has a listener attached for validation. I need to perform calculations on each row summing the cells and creating a running total. When I call a routine to sum the cells my cell variable tfield[x].value is either blank or undefined, depending on where I originally declare tfield[].

```
function createRow1(i) // start create row 
{ 

  row1 = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderColor: '#bbb',
    borderWidth: 1,
    width:'100%', height: 70,
    top: 0, left: 0 });

    var tfield1 = [];
    var label1 =  [];
    var label2 = []; 

    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
       tfield1[i] = Ti.UI.createTextField(baseAttrs); 
       label1[i] = Ti.UI.createLabel(lbAttrs1);
       label2[i] = Ti.UI.createLabel(lbAttrs2);
    }


    tfield1[0].addEventListener('change', function()
    {
       if (tfield1[0].value > 10)
       {
          tfield1[0].value = "";  
          showMessageTimeout("More than 10.",15);
        }
     }); 

   // 6 listeners created, one for each element in the
   // tfield[] array. Omitted for brevity.     

   tfield1[0].left ="0%"; 
   tfield1[1].left ="12%";
   tfield1[2].left ="24%";
   tfield1[3].left ="36%";
   tfield1[4].left ="48%";
   tfield1[5].left ="60%";



   for (i=0;i<6;i++)
   {
      row1.add(tfield1[i]);
      row1.add(label1[i]);
      row1.add(label2[i]);
   }

  return row1;

}  /// end of createrow1

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    row1 = createRow1(i);
    scrollView1.add(row1);
  }

/*
     all six rows are added to a scrollview. A button 
     click fires a listener that sums each row which  
     should also calc a running total of all rows. When 
     called the calc function either shows tfield[] 
     as undeclared or as a blank, depending on 
     where tfield[] is declared.
  */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was answering your last question, but it was deleted.

First of all, your question now isn't so clear as before. I think is the lack of code.

But don't worry, I have all the code you posted. So:

What you are really doing its a matrix of elements, I think an easy way for you to have access to all the textField elements would be:

```
var tfields = [];

buttonCalc.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
   showMessageTimeout("calc pressed",15);
   alert(tfields[0][0].value);
   // alert(tfield1[0].value);  // reference to tfield[0] blows up.

});

...

function createRow1(i) // start create row 
{ 
    ...
    tfields.push(tfield1);  //Add this line here
    return row1;

}  /// end of createrow1
```

I already had answers to all of your other questions, you can make a new question with them :-)

Comment: That's funny :)  I responded to a request to break it up into one question per post with smaller code. Wish I'd waited!

Comment: I created a new question with updated code for the multidimensional array.  Thanks again for the push tip.

Comment: Hi Jocala, I couldn't find the question you mentioned, could you provide me a link? Do you still need help with your other 3 questions? You are wellcome

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224603/update-data-in-matrix-of-cells    I reposted. Not sure what happened to my post last night!