# Update data in matrix of cells

Tags: javascript, scope, titanium

This code implements a 60 cell spreadsheet, 6x10 rows,columns. At the end of each row are two labels, one for row total and for running total. The main issue here is how to update the row and running total labels when the calc button is pressed.

I would also like to move the button from the bottom of the scrollview to the bottom of the window where it's always visible. Another view for buttons at the bottom?

```
Ti.include("toast.js"); // 3rd-party code; displays notifications

var i=0;
var r=0;
var rows = 10;
var columns = 6;

left = ["0%","12%","24%","36%","48%","60%"];



Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Target 1',
    exitOnClose: true,
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
});


win1.addEventListener('androidback' , function(e){
     win1.close();
     var activity = Titanium.Android.currentActivity;
     activity.finish();
});

var scrollView1 = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
  bottom:120,
  contentHeight: 'auto',
  layout: 'vertical'
});


if (Ti.UI.Android){
  win1.windowSoftInputMode = Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN;
}


var buttonCalc = Titanium.UI.createButton({
   title: 'Calc',
   top: 10,
   width: 100,
   height: 50,
   left: "10%"
});




var lbAttrs1 = {
            text: "000",
            left: "74%",
            color:'#000',width:'auto',height:'auto',textAlign:'left',
            font:{fontSize:24,fontWeight:'regular'}
            };


var lbAttrs2 = {
            text: "000",
            left: "88%",
            color:'#000',width:'auto',height:'auto',textAlign:'left',
            font:{fontSize:24,fontWeight:'regular'}
            };


var baseAttrs = {
    borderStyle : Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    keyboardType:  Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBERS_PUNCTUATION,
    maxLength: 2,
    top: 10,
    height: 60,
    value: "",
    width: '12%',
    color : '#000000'
};

 var tfields = [];
 var labels1 =  [];
 var labels2 = []; 


buttonCalc.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{

  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;

for (j=0;j<rows;j++)
{
  a = 0;

  for (i=0;i<columns;i++)
    a = parseInt(tfields[j][i].value) + a; 

   b = b + a;

   labels1[j] = a.toString();
   labels2[j] = b.toString();
}

for (j=0;j<rows;j++)

alert( labels1[j]+'  '+labels2[j]+ ' ' +  j.toString());

});


function createRow1(i) // start create row 

{ 

  row1 = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderColor: '#bbb',
    borderWidth: 1,
    width:'100%', height: 70,
    top: 0, left: 0 });

var tfield1 = [];
var label1 =  [];
var label2 = []; 

for (i=0;i<columns;i++)
  {
    tfield1[i] = Ti.UI.createTextField(baseAttrs); 
    label1[i] = Ti.UI.createLabel(lbAttrs1);
    label2[i] = Ti.UI.createLabel(lbAttrs2);
  }


  tfield1[0].addEventListener('change', function()
    {
    if (tfield1[0].value > 10)
      {
       tfield1[0].value = "";  
       showMessageTimeout("More than 10.",15);
      }
     }); 

 tfield1[1].addEventListener('change', function()
   {
    if (tfield1[1].value > 10)
       {
      tfield1[1].value = "";  
       showMessageTimeout("More than 10.",15);
      }  

    }); 


  tfield1[2].addEventListener('change', function()
   {
    if (tfield1[2].value > 10)
       {
      tfield1[2].value = "";  
       showMessageTimeout("More than 10.",15);
      }
    }); 



  tfield1[3].addEventListener('change', function()
   {
    if (tfield1[3].value > 10)
        {
      tfield1[3].value = "";  
       showMessageTimeout("More than 10.",15);
      }  

    }); 

   tfield1[4].addEventListener('change', function()
   {
    if (tfield1[4].value > 10)
         {
      tfield1[4].value = "";  
       showMessageTimeout("More than 10.",15);
      }    
    }); 

tfield1[5].addEventListener('change', function()
   {
    if (tfield1[5].value > 10)
         {
      tfield1[5].value = "";  
       showMessageTimeout("More than 10.",15);
      }          
   }); 


tfield1[0].left =  left[0];
tfield1[1].left =  left[1];
tfield1[2].left =  left[2];


tfield1[3].left =  left[3];
tfield1[4].left =  left[4];
tfield1[5].left =  left[5];


for (i=0;i<columns;i++)
 {
   row1.add(tfield1[i]);
   row1.add(label1[i]);
   row1.add(label2[i]);
  }

;
tfields.push(tfield1);  
labels1.push(label1);
labels2.push(label2);

return row1;
}  /// end of createrow1

for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
row1 = createRow1(i);
scrollView1.add(row1);
}

win1.add(scrollView1);
scrollView1.add(buttonCalc);
// win1.add(buttonCalc);

win1.open();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point 1.

That is a typo, you should substitute each occurrence of `labels1[j]` and `labels2[j]` to `labels1[j].text` and `labels2[j].text` respectively:

```
buttonCalc.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{

    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;

    for (j=0;j<rows;j++)
    {
        a = 0;

        for (i=0;i<columns;i++){
            var newValue = parseInt(tfields[j][i].value);
            if(!isNaN(newValue) && typeof(newValue) === 'number')
                a = newValue + a;
        } 

        b = b + a;

        labels1[j].text = a.toString();
        labels2[j].text = b.toString();
    }
    for (j=0;j<rows;j++)
        Ti.API.info( labels1[j].text +'  '+labels2[j].text + ' ' +  j.toString());

});
```

And also it must be changed these parts:

```
function createRow1(i) // start create row 
{ 
...
    for (i=0;i<columns;i++)
    {
        tfield1[i] = Ti.UI.createTextField(baseAttrs); 
    }
    label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel(lbAttrs1); //there is only one per row
    label2 = Ti.UI.createLabel(lbAttrs2); //there is only one per row
...
    for (i=0;i<columns;i++)
    {
        row1.add(tfield1[i]);
    }
    row1.add(label1); //there is only one per row
    row1.add(label2); //there is only one per row

    tfields.push(tfield1);  
    labels1.push(label1);
    labels2.push(label2);

    return row1;
}  /// end of createrow1
```

Point 2.

you can do it this way:

```
var scrollView1 = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    top:0,
    height:'60%', //Put your desired value here
    contentHeight: 'auto',
    layout: 'vertical'
});

...

var buttonCalc = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Calc',
    top: '70%', // Put your desired value here greater than scrollView1.height
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    left: "10%"
});

...
win1.add(scrollView1);
//scrollView1.add(buttonCalc);
win1.add(buttonCalc);
```

Extra point.

you need to set  **softKeyboardOnFocus** property in your baseAttrs:

```
    var baseAttrs = {
        borderStyle : Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
        keyboardType:  Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBERS_PUNCTUATION,
        softKeyboardOnFocus: Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS,
        maxLength: 2,
        top: 10,
        height: 60,
        value: "",
        width: '12%',
        color : '#000000'
    };
```

this way, softKeyboard will be shown on focus the first time.

Finally, good luck with your app :-)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I still need to update the total fields at the end of each row (label1[] and label2[]). Doing label1[j].text = labels1[j].text; in the calc function fails because label1 and label2 are seen as undefined, a scope error?

Comment: Alright. I see, I have edited Point 1, now it works well, I've tested on my phone :-) Thanks